# Can I have a constraint which is an enum type associative array size?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to constrain an ENUM type associative array's size:

```
      typedef enum {LOW, MID1, MID2, HIGH} scale;
  
  class seq_item;
  rand bit [7:0] value_a[scale];
  constraint arr_size_c { value_a.num() == 4;}

  endclass

module constraint_example;
  seq_item item;
  
  initial begin
    item = new();
    
    repeat(1) begin
      item.randomize();
      foreach(item.value_a[i]) $display("value[%s] = %0d", i.name(), item.value_a[i]);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

I thought I can have the ENUM type associative array's size when I ran the simulation I got
the below error randomize method call failed message.

```
      celium> run
      item.randomize();
                   |
xmsim: *W,SVRNDF (./testbench.sv,18|19): The randomize method call failed. The unique id of the failed randomize call is 0.
Observed simulation time : 0 FS + 0
xmsim: *W,RNDOCS: These constraints contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:

  constraint arr_size_c { value_a.num() == 4;} (./testbench.sv,7)

xmsim: *W,RNDOCS: These variables contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:


Var_Name                Type   Status        Current_Value          Source                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
value_a.size            (U31)  STATE VAR     0 (0x0)                ./testbench.sv ; line 6
```

Trying to find the reason of error, I have checked the size of `value_a` and it is '0' not 4.
Even if I commented out `constraint arr_size_c {value_a.size() == 4;}` then still I get the '0'.

Is this not available to get an ENUM type associative array size as I do `value_a[]` in the constraint?

Actually I expected that I can get the randomized array with print().

```
value[LOW] = 15
value[MID1] = 37
value[MID2] = 54
value[HIGH] = 86
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot randomize the size of an associative array because there is no way to allocate array elements without defining the keys/indices first.

What you can do is allocate the array elements before calling `randomize()`, and then randomize the array element values later.

```
 class seq_item;
  rand bit [7:0] value_a[scale];
  function new;
    scale idx = idx.first();
    do begin
      value_a[idx]=0;
      idx = idx.next();
    end while (idx != idx.first());
  endfunction
  endclass
```